# Zend form Label does not render with accents

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am trying to render a form  which contains accents in the `setlabel` method like:

```
$ticketNumber->setLabel("Endere&ccedil;o");
```

I have tried every single option out there from forums. but it does not work, it displays the `&atilde` instead of the true value of that entity.

I addition. if i try the following, the text for the label does not render(the label is blank) at all.

```
$ticketNumber->setLabel("Endereço");
```

In my application.ini have added the following:

```
resources.view.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
```

I really don't know what is wrong. I've been fighting this for couple of days now.
Any help is welcomed.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ticketNumber->setLabel("Endereço");
```

is correct. But you're then telling it to use an encoding where ç is not a valid character. You need to switch that to UTF-8 or similar:

```
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

Comment: If i change it to  UTF-8 the label is not rendered at all.Comes back blank. Any more ideas? thanks

Comment: Make sure your DB connection is also using UTF-8, and you have a UTF-8 header in the `<head>` section of your page.

Comment: Just to be sure that it's an encoding issue and not that your decorators are dropping the label: If you use a pure ASCII value for the label text, does it display?

Comment: if i use the ASCII  value is displays ths ascii value itself.